# Web based data visualization with pure CSS3/HTML5?

Tags: html, css, charts, mapping

Is there's at least basic drawing that can be done without without JS library like D3 / Anychart / Charts.js etc.

Can pure HTML5 / CSS3 do something like this map https://vida.io/gists/FLFFovRPbu2t5QwQC/index.html

Map interaction is optional.

Comment: you could create that map with many SVG paths: see http://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=usa download the SVG and open it with a text editor

Comment: Any example or tutorial link?

Comment: The SVG file contains the markup of the SVG element to insert into the page

Answer (score 0):

of course you can, you can create map using svg, svg elements can be treated as html elements so you can use css selectors like `:hover` and use it for showing your custom titles on hover. Only thing, which cant be done without using js is, that theese titles will follow your cursor. They can be at given position, but i'm not aware of way to position them depending on cursor position using css